# How to finish the FBS "Trade 100 Bonus"

Tags: foreign-exchange

I started the process of learning how to trade on Forex, and came across FBS' "Trade 100 Bonus".

I created an account, and then saw that they require that, in 50 days, you opened or closed orders in at least 30 days, and traded 5 standard lots. Considering that the only size I can use is 0.01 lots, I need to make at least 500 orders, with at least 251 succesful ones. And all of those need to have at least 100 pips of profit, that I never got in my demo account.

Is my understanding right? If yes, I have more to do, I can't trade all day for a month! How can I accomplish all the requirements? If not, what really are the requirements?